# SQLAlchemy hybrid_property expression with foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm kind of new to SQLAlchemy, and a bit confused about how to create a `hybrid_property` expression when there are foreign keys involved. Here are the declarative classes I'm using:

```
class ProductColor(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'productcolor'
    value = Column(Text, nullable=False, unique=True)
    rgb = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    cmyk = Column(Text)


class ProductVariant(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'productvariant'
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'),
                        nullable=False)
    product = relationship('Product', backref='variants')
    color1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ProductColor.id), nullable=False)
    color1 = relationship(ProductColor, foreign_keys=color1_id)
    color2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ProductColor.id))
    color2 = relationship(ProductColor, foreign_keys=color2_id)
    is_display_color = Column(Boolean, default=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def slug(self):
        return u''.join((self.color1.value, getattr(self.color2, 'value', '')))

    @slug.expression
    def slug(cls):
        pass # What do i write here?
```

The instance property works fine, but I'm unsure what to put in the expression property. I've tried the following but it gives me `AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with ProductVariant.color1 has an attribute 'value'`:

```
@slug.expression
    def slug(cls):
        return cls.color1.value + cls.color2.value
```

**EDIT**

I've also tried the following but then get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'corresponding_column'`:

```
@slug.expression
def slug(cls):
    color1 = aliased(ProductColor, 'color1')
    color2 = aliased(ProductColor, 'color2')
    return (select([func.concat(color1.value, color2.value)])
            .join(color1).filter(color1.value == cls.color1.value)
            .outerjoin(color2).filter(color2.value == cls.color2.value)
            .as_scalar())
```

Do you guys have any good solution to this?